# How is the value of a begin block determined?

Tags: ruby, expression, block

According to [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) p.164.

> If a `begin` statement doesn't propagate an exception, then the value
>   of the statement is **the value of the last expression** evaluated in
>   the `begin`, `rescue` or `else` clauses.

But I found this behavior consistent with the **begin block** together with **else clause** and **ensure clause**.

Here is the example code:

```
def fact (n)
  raise "bad argument" if n.to_i < 1
end

value = begin
  fact (1)
rescue RuntimeError => e
  p e.message
else
  p "I am in the else statement"
ensure
  p "I will be always executed"
  p "The END of begin block"
end

p value
```

The output is:

```
"I am in the else statement"
"I will be always executed"
"The END of begin block"
"I am in the else statement"
[Finished]
```

The `value` is evaluated to the **else clause**. This is inconsistent behavior as the **ensure clause** is the last statement executed.

Could someone explain what's happening within the begin block?

Comment: "block of code is evaluated for the last statement executed". This is obviously a wrong assumption.

Comment: Sorry, correct with more specific statement and references.

Comment: Now you answered the question yourself: "begin, rescue or else" is in fact the correct order, so this is consistent with the specification.

Comment: So you mean, the specification should be interpreted as "the value of the last expression evaluated in the **(order of)** begin, rescue or else clauses"? It makes sense here.

Comment: Yes, that's how I'd interpret that sentence.

Comment: It explains the behavior. Wanna upvote your interpretation ;)

Comment: Note that even if the assumption about the order is wrong, `ensure` is not even that list, so the `begin` block cannot possibly evaluate to the `ensure` clause.

Comment: By the way, looking through rubyspec, I can't find this being specified, so I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Know where should I find the related source code [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd interpret the goal of the `begin/rescue/else/end` block as:

- Execute the code in the `begin` section, and then the code in the `else` section.
- If something goes wrong in the `begin` section, execute the `rescue` section instead of the `else` section.

So **either** the `rescue` section or the `else` section will be executed after trying the `begin` section; so it makes sense that one of them will be used as the whole block's value.

It's simply a side effect that the `ensure` section will always be executed.

```
val = begin
  p "first"; "first"
rescue => e
  p "fail"; "fail"
else
  p "else"; "else"
ensure
  p "ensure"; "ensure"
end

val # => "else"
# >> "first"
# >> "else"
# >> "ensure"
```

But:

```
val = begin
  p "first"; "first"
  raise
rescue => e
  p "fail"; "fail"
else
  p "else"; "else"
ensure
  p "ensure"; "ensure"
end

val # => "fail"
# >> "first"
# >> "fail"
# >> "ensure"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but as the purpose of a ensure block is to finalize any resources that may remain open (cleanup in other words), and so it makes sense that the logical value should be the result of the else statement.   It makes sense to me that it is by design.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `begin` block is just a way of defining a section for which you may want to do exception handling.

Remember that `else` in this case runs if no exceptions occur, and `ensure` will run regardless of exceptions or a lack thereof.