# How to build chain of block-rescue dynamically?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is that possible to build a chain of `block`/`rescue` like this one **dynamically**, e.g from an array of symbols `[:f1, :f2, :f3, f4]`. The code below is supposed to mimick what I would write **statically**:

```
  begin
    applyF1()
  rescue
    applyF2()
    begin
      applyF3()
    rescue
      applyF4()
    end
  end
```

I already know how to send a built message from symbols (`object.send(message)`), so `applyFx` is not the problem.

Comment: Is the block structure constant? I mean, are the functions which will be called the only variables here?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly reasonable question, even though there may be better ways to accomplish what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: First, using camel case for a method/variable in Ruby sucks. Second, using an empty `()` for method in Ruby sucks. Third, the connection between `:f1` and `applyF1` is not clear. Why not write `send(:f1)`? That makes it much clearer, and the OP would not have to put an excuse that `applyFx` is not a problem. Fourth, and most importantly, the rule is not clear. Why are `applyF1` and `applyF3` in `begin` `rescue` but not `applyF2` and `applyF4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the behavior you really expected, because as @sawa, I don't see you are treating `applyF{1..4}` equally either.

This snippet shows how to evaluate a few lambdas in turn, until one of them returns a non-false value without raising anything.

If you want to evaluate `applyF{1..?}` in pairs ( when `F1` failed, recover by `F2`, then try with `F3` and recover by `F4` when fail, and so on ), you can make `applyF{2,4,..}` always return nil.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

blocks = {
  a: ->(){ raise "raise" },
  b: ->(){ raise "also raise" },
  c: ->(){ :finished },
  d: ->(){ "won't be executed" },
}

ret = blocks.reduce(nil) do |has_succeeded, (key, lam)|
  has_succeeded ||=
  begin
    puts "trying #{key.inspect}"
    lam.call # when succeed, the lambda should return a non-false value
  rescue => e
    puts "failed with message=<#{e.message}>. trying next"
    nil
    # no else clause here, so
    # if lam.call raises nothing, memo keep its return value, and prevents calling following {lam}s.
    # if something is raised in lam.call, this block evalutes to nil
  end
end

# will print:
# trying :a
# failed with message=<raise>. trying next
# trying :b
# failed with message=<also raise>. trying next
# trying :c

p ret
# => :finished
```

reference : [How is the value of a begin block determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687579/how-is-the-value-of-a-begin-block-determined)

Answer (score 0):

This is the first that comes to my mind:

```
def rescueChain(*args)
  args.each do |f|
    begin
      <... apply f here ...>
      return  # Exits from the entire function.
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

I didn't test it yet.